# Calling (importing) other .lua files outside main.lua in Love2D

Tags: love2d

So, I wanted to clean up my code by splitting it into seperate files. But for some reason I can't call the script I want to call through my main.lua.

Here's my main.lua script:

```lua
function love.load()
  require "splash.lua"
  splash.load()
end

function love.update(dt)
  splash.update(dt)

end

function love.draw() print("Draw")
  splash.draw()
  love.graphics.print("FPS "..tostring(love.timer.getFPS( )), 5, 5) print("fps")
  love.graphics.setColor(255,0,0) --Red
  love.graphics.rectangle("fill", 3, 3, 60, 20)
end
```

And here's my splash.lua script, separate from the main.lua file:

```lua
function splash.load()
    timer = 0 print("fadein")
    alpha = 0
    fadein  = 2
    display = 4
    fadeout = 6
    splashScreen = love.graphics.newImage("/images/Splash1.png")
end

function splash.update(dt)
    timer = timer + dt
    if 0 < timer and timer < fadein then
        alpha = timer / fadein
    end
    if fadein < timer and timer < display then
        alpha = 1
    end
    if display < timer and timer < fadeout then
        alpha = 1 - ((timer - display) / (fadeout - display))
    end
end

function splash.draw()
    love.graphics.setColor(1, 1, 1, alpha)
    local sx = love.graphics.getWidth() / splashScreen:getWidth()
    local sy = love.graphics.getHeight() / splashScreen:getHeight()
    love.graphics.draw(splashScreen, 0, 0, 0, sx, sy)
end
```

I've searched everywhere on this topic, and the other answers are either extremely vague or outdated. All I want to do is to make the splash.lua run when I start Love.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were two problems which I noticed and once I fixed them something ran.

**Problem 1**
In main.lua, `require "splash.lua"` should be `require "splash"`. If you code in other languages like python, java or javascript, you can think of require as similar to import.

**Problem 2**
In splash.lua, you are referencing an object(splash) which doesn't exist. To keep your code as similar as I could, I inserted the line `splash = {}` at the top of splash.lua. Once the object `splash` is created, you are then able to create functions for this object(splash.load(), splash.update(), and splash.draw()). This isn't a problem in main.lua because `love` is an object which already exists when the love2d game engine starts.

**main.lua**

```lua
function love.load()
  require "splash"
  splash.load()
end

function love.update(dt)
  splash.update(dt)
end

function love.draw() print("Draw")
  splash.draw()
  love.graphics.print("FPS "..tostring(love.timer.getFPS( )), 5, 5) print("fps")
  love.graphics.setColor(255,0,0) --Red
  love.graphics.rectangle("fill", 3, 3, 60, 20)
end
```

**splash.lua**

```lua
splash = {}

function splash.load()
    timer = 0 print("fadein")
    alpha = 0
    fadein  = 2
    display = 4
    fadeout = 6
    splashScreen = love.graphics.newImage("/images/Splash1.png")
end

function splash.update(dt)
    timer = timer + dt
    if 0 < timer and timer < fadein then
        alpha = timer / fadein
    end
    if fadein < timer and timer < display then
        alpha = 1
    end
    if display < timer and timer < fadeout then
        alpha = 1 - ((timer - display) / (fadeout - display))
    end
end

function splash.draw()
    love.graphics.setColor(1, 1, 1, alpha)
    local sx = love.graphics.getWidth() / splashScreen:getWidth()
    local sy = love.graphics.getHeight() / splashScreen:getHeight()
    love.graphics.draw(splashScreen, 0, 0, 0, sx, sy)
end
```

---

**Side note**: from reading your code, I'm not sure if you understand entirely how the load, update, and draw functions work. Love is an object created by the love2d game engine. The engine runs the load function only once when the game starts. The update function then continually checks for changes to the world that the game exists in and applies the code within love.update according to the conditions inside it. The draw function continually draws what it is told over and over again. These things happen automatically because it's already programmed into the love2d game engine.
The only reason I think you might be confused in this area is that you created a separate `splash.load`, `splash.update`, and `splash.draw`. You can technically name whatever functions you're calling anything you want, I just had the feeling that you might think that these load, update and draw functions might be called automatically, which they're not. Love2d only calls the load, update, and draw functions automatically for the `love` object.

Comment: Hey Jacob, thanks so much for your answer, it worked perfectly. Just wanted to clarify with you that I understand that the `love` object is the only one that is called when the code is running. But isn't this only true with the `main.lua`? I assumed that Love2D just ignored any other `love` calls that were outside the `main.lua`. Feel free to correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @Koto Yep it looks like you understand it, I just wasn't sure because you had specifically created other `load` `update` and `draw` functions. I believe that it's only in `main.lua`. I also thought the explanation might help explain why none of the splash functions might be able to be called.

Answer (score -1):

Changing your `require` command to the following should work:

```lua
require("splash")
```

Additionally you should create the `splash` table before creating functions for said table.

```lua
splash = {}

splash.myFunction()
.
.
.
```